# SonarQube 5.2 + Javascript 2.8 sonar.exclusions not honoured

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 5.2 with Javascript plugin 2.8. I can not seem to prevent generated Javascript files (created by com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:minify) from being analyzed by SonarQube. I find no way to configure this property in the SonarQube administrative interface. I also try with $PROJECT/sonar-project.properties with only 1 line:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/all-script.js,**/all-script.min.js,**/all-style.css,**/all-style.min.css
```

Having these files being scanned is generating hundreds upon hundreds of warnings of Major severity. The modular version of these javascript/css files have only a couple of warnings. How can I avoid the analysis of these generated javascript and css files without changing their final location on the file system?

Comment: What's the path of the file that you want to exclude?

Comment: $PROJECT/$MODULE/src/main/webapp/all-script.js, etc, please don't suggest I change this location, it is required for me to have it there so that Apache TomEE can find it after Eclipse runs the minify:minify goal after I make a change to a corresponding resource.

Comment: I don't manage to reproduce your issue, your configuration looks good. The only problem I could imagine is if you define exclusions at module level, e.g. module1.sonar.exclusions=**/foo.js, which would override sonar.exclusions. The logs of your analysis should display which exclusions are taken into account: you can look for "Excluded sources:" in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get the sonar-project.properties file method working, but I was able to to pass **-Dsonar.exclusions=**/all-script.js,**/all-script.min.js,**/all-style.css,**/all-style.min.css** via Jenkins properties to our Apache Maven invocation. That worked. :-)