# How to exclude a subfolder of compiled resources from a Sonar analysis?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate Sonarqube analysis into the JavaScript sources of my project. It is a project using Spring components for the back-end, and as a first step, we did the integration of Java sources, without problem at that point.

We are using Sonarqube v5.6.3

The problem I am finding comes with the `sonar.exclusions` property. Apparently, that property can't exclude a folder that has already been added as sources (see [question and answer explaining that exact issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176126/using-sonar-test-exclusions-with-sonarqube-6-3)).

I have the following lines in my pom.xml, which are not working properly; and that's understandable according to the aforelinked question:

```
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java,src/main/docker,js-sources</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/target/*</sonar.exclusions>
```

The problem is: the front-end is made of several modules which are compiled one by one under their own `/target` sub-folder before being deployed all together into `src/main/webapp`. (They work as regular target folders: when a new compilation is launched, those folders get deleted/recreated.)

Those `js-sources/moduleA/target`, `js-sources/moduleB/target`,  `js-sources/moduleC/target` folders are being automatically included as sources, and thus ignored by the exclusions directive. Those target folder still contain a /src subfolder, which makes it hard to use the limited Sonar patterns (full xpath-like selectors are not allowed) to include or exclude only certain paths.

As I don't think that the Sonarqube team was expecting everyone to add each little subfolder one by one (that's why they made patterns in the first term), I am looking for help: **How do I exclude those per-module target folders living down the folder-tree inside my sources?**

Another possibility would be that it is kind of a bug forcing us to [store this config at a Jenkinsfile or even directly in the Jenkins config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079635/sonarqube-5-2-javascript-2-8-sonar-exclusions-not-honoured) (at a job level), but I remain unsure and still think that something can be fixed in the way I am declaring the sources and exclusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 <sonar.exclusions>**/target/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
```

Comment: The solution was at hand from the very beginning! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : while inclusions are useful in other cases, the accepted answer above is the correct one. I'm leaving mine, which follows, for the record and just as an example of using inclusions.

Try using inclusions rather than exclusions, I've setup a project as close to yours as I could guess from your description and I was able to ignore the target folders of the js-sources modules :

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java,js-sources</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.inclusions>**/*.java, **/src/**/*.js</sonar.inclusions>
</properties>
```

You can read this as : 'scan all java files no matter where they are, scan only the javascript files that are found within the src of a subfolder of root'

Comment: thanks, @carlo! the tip of using inclusions instead of exclusions seems to point in the right direction. the issue is that both the source for each javascript module and the target are inside a `/src` subfolder (the target subfolder also has the compiled files which will be later deployed), and due to the limited pattern we're allowed to use (not full xpath selectors, in any case), i'm starting to think i dont have a way to filter those out